# How to process with error in MySQL bat file?

Tags: mysql, batch-file

I have such a `.bat` file

```
@echo off
set sql_bin_path=%MY_SQL%
cd /d %sql_bin_path%

mysqldump -u root -p --no-data test > test.sql


pause
goto :eof

:error
echo Something went wrong
pause
```

I need to catch a possible error in this line `mysqldump -u root -p --no-data test > test.sql` (for example if there isn't such db name) and move the execution to `goto :error` block

How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command `mysqldump` has a return status, which can be 0, 1 or 2.
That can be captured and based on that, you can decide what to do.

More explanation can be found in [this ServerFault post](https://serverfault.com/questions/249853/does-mysqldump-return-a-status).

In case if you use `.bat` file the solution is:

```
@echo off
set sql_bin_path=%MY_SQL%
cd /d %sql_bin_path%

mysqldump -u root -p --no-data test > test.sql

if %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 (goto error)
echo MySQL was dumped successfully  

pause
goto :eof

:error
echo Something went wrong
pause
```